# CAN j1939 support in Linux Kernel 4.x

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, can-bus, socketcan, j1939

Any one have ported CAN J1939 stack on the kernel 4.x series?

We had ported it into 3.10 kernel based on the link "http://elinux.org/J1939".
Now I want to port it into the kernel version 4.1.15. I understand there was some changes happens in the 4.x kernel network layer and my current patches shows some errors?
Have anyone already ported this into 4.x kernel? or from where can I get the patches for new Kernel ?
Please advice me?

Thanks,
Shabeer

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are typically off-site for SO. Please see the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand what questions you can ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw it done in Yocto for some kernels. Though, if you google for it you may find the following link: http://elinux.org/J1939. I checked repositories, it contains a branch for v4.1 version.

Comment: Hi  Andy Shevchenko,